# How to correctly type a JavaScript object used as a map in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JavaScript object with the following structure:

```
{
  "_index": 1,
  "foo": { ... },
  "bar": { ... },
  "baz": { ... },
}
```

That is, the object will *always* have one property `_index` with a number value, and then all the other keys (which aren't defined since its being used as a map) have a value of another, specific, object.

I have tried the following types in TypeScript

```
type Properties = {
  _index: number
}

type Fields = {
   // its not important what Metadata is, just that it has a type that isn't number
  [field: string]: Metadata
}

type Lookup = Properties & Fields
```

This works well for accessing an already created instance of `Lookup` in TypeScript, but I don't seem to be able to *create* an instance of `Lookup` in TypeScript.

For example, if I do this:

```
let lookup: Lookup = {
  _index: 1,
  foo: { ... }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
2322[QF available]: Type '{ _index: number; "foo": { ... }' is not assignable to type 'Lookup'. Type '{      _index: number; "foo": { ... }' is not assignable to type 'Fields'. Property '_index' is incompatible with index signature. Type             'number' is not assignable to type 'Metadata'
```

What is the best way to express this type in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Typescript will not let you create such objects directly. Although the type system allows you to create such a type, it is a bit inconsistent, since `lookup['_index']`does not actually conform to the index signature which should always return `Metadata`

The simplest way to create such an object is to use `Object.assign`

```
let lookup: Lookup = Object.assign({ _index: 1 }, {
    x: {}
})
```

Comment: Using `Object.assign` that way kind of makes sense with the type `Foo = Bar & Baz`, create a `Bar`, create a `Baz` then merge them together to get a `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

Just merge your definitions like this:

`type Lookup = {[field: string]: Metadata, _index: number}`

This will define an interface Lookup with definitely an index and then any other properties with the type metadata.

Comment: That doesn't work though right? I get `Property '_index' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'Metadata`. You _could_ get around that by having `_index` be either `number` or `Metadata` but that makes working with the object a bit harder.

Comment: Updated the answer. You were right, I had the wrong order.